# How can I rename a file but display the original file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my ASP.NET application, users can upload PDF files and view them at a later point. After running into problems with unicode characters, I've been advised that it's generally good practice to not let users choose the file names of uploaded files. I'm renaming them now, but the user should see the original filename in order to know what file to open. Is it possible to store that original filename as some sort of meta data? I'm thinking about saving it in the ViewBag and somehow make a connection to the new filename..

Comment: Store it in a database with 2 columns, original name and renamed name. But you also should think what happens if a user uploads a file with the same name as other previously uploaded.

Comment: What problems were you having with unicode characters? Why not try to fix those instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be storing details in a Viewbag. The dynamic variable will be lost if you do not capture it repeatedly (during controller method, at view level, after controller is executed)

Viewbag is not something which is persistent. Your best bet is to store the values in a database.

I would create a log table which keeps track of the file history. Maybe consider the columns contentid, oldname,newname,date in a new table

contentid - a guid which stores the reference of the article/item being modified
oldname - old filename
newname - new filename
date - date on which this transaction has been done